# How to evaluate a complex-valued integral?

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

If I wish to calculate the integral: $$\int_a^b |e^{\pi i nx}|^2dx,$$ am I allowed to simply note that the norm must equal one, so wouldn't we have: $$\int_a^b |e^{\pi i nx}|^2dx = b - a.$$

Another related question: Do we have:

$$\int_a^b (e^{\pi i nx})^cdx = \int_a^b e^{c\pi i nx}dx?$$ I am not sure if this is allowed if the exponent is complex-valued. Thanks!

Comment: Are you taking a complex variables course?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the answer is yes -- you're correct. To answer the second question, the equation doesn't necessarily hold. In general, the value of $(e^{2\pi inx})^c$ the integrand depends on the choice of branch of the power function $z^c$.

Comment: Can you elaborate upon the choice of branch? When would the equality not hold?

Comment: Note $\arg(e^{\pi i nx}) = \pi nx + 2\pi k$, where $k$ is any integer. So $$\log(e^{\pi i nx}) = \log|e^{\pi inx}| + i\arg(e^{\pi inx}) = \log 1 + i(\pi nx + 2\pi k) = i(\pi nx + 2\pi k),$$ and therefore $$(e^{\pi i nx})^c = e^{c\log(e^{\pi inx})} = e^{ic(\pi nx + 2\pi k)} = e^{\pi in cx}e^{2\pi ikc}.$$